# ArrayList search value

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist which is conformed of objects which have a name and a value
so the arraylist is:

```
name  value
A     1
B     10
C     23
D     45
```

How would you loop the ArrayList searching for 2 names like C and D, and get their respective values: 23, and 45?

Comment: What kind of objects are in the list? Your "structure" is unclear to those of us to can't see your code.

Comment: Sorry, what? `Arraylist` is not key->value like a `HashMap` or similar is. Your question makes no sense.

Comment: Are your name-value pairs stored in an object that you've defined? ArrayLists typically take a single data type e.g. `ArrayList<Integer>` or `ArrayList<String>`, unless you've defined some kind of object that has both as instance variables. You might want to investigate the `HashMap<ElemType, ElemType>` collection class instead.

Comment: Yes my arraylist is of type node wich has several elements, but I am only interested in name and value..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean that you have objects in the array list which have a name and value?

You could do something like this:

```
for(MyObj obj : list) {
    if(obj.getName().equals("C") || obj.getName().equals("A")){
          System.out.println("Value: " + obj.getValue);
    }
}
```

But your best bet may be to create a Hashmap of String to value:

```
Map<String, Integer> valueMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Then you can simply call

```
valueMap.get("A");
```

which will return the value associated with A.

Comment: How is that supposed to work? Object has no method 'getName()'. You'd have to create a subclass and implement that method.

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry I wrote object when it should have been anything else.

Comment: `Map<String, int> valueMap = new HashMap<String, int>();` get me an error `int`, how to declare it

Comment: oh sorry it should be Integer rather than int.

Comment: and how do I insert elements in hash

Comment: you need to use the put method provided on the map.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (MyObj obj : list) {
    // Here check if obj.getAAA() equals to "C" etc
}
```